# Two-columns table in tabularx with \textwidth

Tags: tables, tabularx, width, textwidth

I have a problem with setting up a table, created in `tabularx`, to the text width of my article. What can I do?

Here is the dummy example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{ltablex,booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[100]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lX}
\caption{cccc} \\
\toprule
\textbf{Definition} & \textbf{Counts} \\
\midrule

\textit{A}             &  68\\ 
\textit{B}             &  10\\
\textit{C}             &  10\\
\midrule
$\sum$                 &  88\\

\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

The PDF view:

[image: example]

Comment: At least one `X` column is required.

Comment: It is not solving my problem. I fixed the code and still nothing

Comment: Could you post a full compilable code, not just a snippet?

Comment: (i) please provide complete small document  with your table and image of table (your table has width of text).; (ii) off-topic: `\caption` should not be inside `tabularx` environment

Comment: Your code doesn't even load `tabularx`!

Comment: The code is updated including a PDF viewer. I disagree Zarko, if I put `\caption` somewhere else, I get an error message that the table is outside of `float`. Maybe you mix it up with normal `\table` or `\tabular` environment

Comment: @Zarko is totally right: use `\caption` outside of `tabularx` but wrap everything in a `table` environment.

Comment: While you wait for an answer to this question, can you go back to your previous ones and look if the answers solve your problems and accept them, if they do?

Comment: please always post a _complete_ small document that shows the problem, I would guess you are using the  `ltablex` package but you do not say.

Comment: do not link to external sites, edit your code block so the example document is in the question.

Comment: but if you are using ltablex then use `\keepXcolumns`

Comment: Yes, I use the `\ltablex` in my code. Since I write an article and use a lot of packages, I thought sharing a link is the best idea but apparently, it's not. I'll get rid of it then and past all the packages manually. Sorry, for the confusion!

Comment: if you fix the tabularx usage then the table will be expanded to `\textwidth` and be almost impossible for anyone to read as the data will be so separated it will be hard to see the association across a row. I would just use `tabular` here.

Comment: @Jo-Achna your question is archived on this site _forever_ unless you can arrange that your overleaf link stays unchanged then the question and answers will not make sense if you fix the issue in teh overleaf sources.

Comment: @David Carlisle: Yeah, I realized that a bit late, but again I got rid of the link and pasted the entire preamble of my article. It's not "small" as some required me to do but it's a 1:1 copy of my document. So you suggest to use `\tabluar ` in my case

Comment: Please always test the document you post, (and think of people trying to help who may need to trace the code) your code still can not be run (missing (`\begin{document}..\end{document}` ) and has lots of irrelevant packages. See the version i posted in my answer.

Comment: Code fixed! Solution found! Mission accomplished!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

This is a `ltablex` "feature" which you can turn off as shown, however there is no reason to stretch the tabular, it just makes it harder to read, if you use a centered `tabular` it is fine.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{ltablex,booktabs}
\keepXColumns
\begin{document}


\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lX}
\caption{cccc} \\
\toprule
\textbf{Definition} & \textbf{Counts} \\
\midrule

\textit{A}             &  68\\ 
\textit{B}             &  10\\
\textit{C}             &  10\\
\midrule
$\sum$                 &  88\\

\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Carlile: I found the solution! It looks it's not enough to add `\keepXColumns`, as you suggested, but I had to tweak a bit the line `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lX}` to the following one `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{Xr}`